# COUNT the output of CASE WHEN

Tags: sql, postgresql

I need to do a count on the output of a query on a psql instance.

I've tried making it into a sub-query in a number of different configurations.

I want to take the output of this query and do a count on the newly created testgroup column.

```
SELECT userid,
   CASE WHEN COUNT(type) filter (WHERE type = 'web') <= COUNT(type) filter (WHERE type = 'mobile') THEN 'GROUPA'
   ELSE 'GROUPB'
   END AS testgroup  FROM logins
   GROUP BY userid
   ORDER BY userid;
```

OUTPUT

[image]

DESIRED OUTPUT

[image]

Comment: not sure what you mean here as the example data does not match the query you have tryed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One method is a subquery:

```
SELECT testgroup, COUNT(*)
FROM (SELECT userid,
             (CASE WHEN COUNT(type) filter (WHERE type = 'web') <= COUNT(type) filter (WHERE type = 'mobile')
                   THEN 'GROUPA'
                   ELSE 'GROUPB'
              END) AS testgroup
     FROM logins
     GROUP BY userid
    ) u
GROUP BY testgroup
```

Comment: That is exactly what i was trying to do. What is the significance of the "u" on the line above the group by.

Comment: *"What is the significance of the "u" on the line above the group by. "* @scarey9 do you understand  `") AS u"` instead? it's just a simple table alias for a deliverd table (subquery)